# playing streamed content in an app

Tags: iphone, quicktime

I have a number of music tracks which I would like the user to be able to preview a small clip of each.

These tracks are on a server.

How is media streamed into the app and which player is used? Can a custom player be created to play the clips within the view, without e.g. quicktime player opening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use QuickTime, the matter is rather complex, as far as I know. Fortunately, a lot of work already has been done for you by Matt Gallagher. See [this excelent post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/revisiting-old-post-streaming-and.html) for further information. The code, that he provides works perfectly in my application.